# Overlay an image/button to the homescreen/ Android

Tags: java, android, button

I have a simple question.. I've looked online and couldn't find an answer.. If someone can point me in the right direction is all I'm asking. There are a few apps out there that can put a translucent button on your screen that will remain static.. Even if apps open.. Can someone point me in the right direction to learn how to do this

Comment: can you give an example? I'm not visualizing it.

Comment: yes, and overlay(on top of), your home screen. apps, etc, a static button that will not move. An app that will run on top of your android interface. just a button I can place on the screen to that will always be available for them to press. Ive seen it done before in a few apps, like a screen capture app that uses a little image of a camera on the top-right of the screen that can pressed to take pictures in apps...

Comment: Huh. Never heard of this. I can imagine putting something in the status bar. My Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 has a 4th button at the bottom that can be set to do a screenshot, but I always assumed that was android or Samsung OS behavior.